# How to use Vuetify's parent activator from inside a custom component

Tags: vuejs3, dialog, vuetifyjs3

Vuetify 3's `VDialog` has the `activator` prop that can be used like this:

```html
<VBtn>
  Click me to show a dialog
  <VDialog activator="parent">
    Ta-da!
  </VDialog>
</VBtn>
```

But there's this dialog that I use similarly multiple times throughout the app. So I want to abstract it away into its own component. Like this:

```html
<!-- MyDialog.vue -->
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  activator: String,
});
</script>

<template>
  <VDialog :activator="props.activator">
    Ta-da!
  </VDialog>
</template>
```

And then in the parent...

```html
<VBtn>
  Click me to show a dialog
  <MyDialog activator="parent" />
</VBtn>
```

But this doesn't seem to work. It looks like `<VDialog>`'s parent is the `<template>`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: it should work https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNptUEFqwzAQ/MpWl7RgSwe3FIxTKPRaWmjppe5BlZUgsCWx2piEkL9HtmKTkBx3dmd2Zn73LKASr97zfqNZyaqg0HiCoGnjX2oLYDrvkOB992Zk69awQtfBgosJGIiL2lYiMSOnIt35VpIe+VVjelCtDGFZM9JbypW2pLFm4zoe9Pk/WVCudRhPPJpO4m5eA3x4bSE9m6BqtiMVmV5SokqM0jUDMUmLUTv5ENHI4E6c2WPZmP88y80SlLOBwKPzAZbQ6JWx+nOY7vfp02yjhC9CY9fZgB8eLoq5qubnFKK8SDHo8hmJRcC3zBt5FyOcCFcxDhkr+CN/jnkK/sQL9ncE5Kyeqg==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  activator: String,
});
</script>
```

does not expose a `props` variable to `<template />`. Instead, it exposes each individual prop as a variable. Which means the correct template would be:

```html
<template>
  <VDialog :activator="activator">
    Ta-da!
  </VDialog>
</template>
```

---

If the above doesn't help, I suggest you create a *runnable* [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to allow debugging and testing any potential solution. If you need a node-like online environment, use codesandbox.io or similar.